# Help with hovering field data

Tags: theming

Drupal demi-gods,

I have a scenario as follows in a "Reference data" content type

Code                 Description
NY                    New York
CA                      California
CO                       Colorado and so on

I want to have say an Address content type that references these state codes, simple enough, define a node reference for the content type, but in addition, i want to be able to hover over the drop down box of states, in the address content, and for Drupal to list the state in a hover text.

Can anyone tell me if there is any functionality that provides this, or does it require coding? If it does require coding, which file should I be modifying?

Thanks heaps, I've been struggling with this for a few days now.

Geoff

Answer (score 0):

A view with an exposed filter is what you are looking for.

Create a view with the fields that you want to show, and select the state code field as an exposed filter. Then the view will display only the content related to the state code selected by the user. The view may contain only one field, or many. If the relevant fields are in different entity/content types, you will need to define a Relationship in the view to *connect* them using an entity or node reference field.

Using Views you can get almost *everything* that you want if all the data involved is related. If you give us more concrete details about what you want to achieve, I could give you precise details of how to configure the View that will solve your problem.